# iPhone 4S message to enter password for CalDAV

Tags: iphone

My iPhone is asking me to enter the password for the CalDav account "Yahoo".  What does this mean?  Do I have to do it? Can I stop it from asking for it?

Comment: Where is the message popping up? Calendar app? Mail app?

Comment: I assume you *do* have a Yahoo account configured in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, often when it asks for a password, the original one was entered incorrectly - something very easy to do on an iPhone. First, try entering the password to see if it goes away. Chances are, it is probably not syncing with your Yahoo calendar and won't unless the password problem is corrected.

You can also go to **Settings** > **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**, and select the account named "Yahoo", and turn off the calendar for that account if you do not wish to have it in the Calendar app.

If you currently are receiving mail to that Yahoo account (if there is one associated with it) on your phone, then it may be a different problem.

Comment: I had the same issue happen to my mum on her iPad and this is how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had deleted one of my email accounts from my home computer. I had forgotten to remove it from my phone. went in to settings - mail, contacts, calendars and removed it. No more calDav message.